# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is querying a DC which is no longer in production

Tags: .net, iis, active-directory

We have a Web App that uses System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to check if a user is authenticated. We recently powered off one of the DC's as it is going to get demoted.

The web App keeps saying it can not reach the DC which was powered off (and removed from DNS).

Does anyone know how the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement cache's data for DCs to query and how we could resolve the issue of the system looking at a DC which no longer exist

The line of code [Checking to see if the user is authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J08Nq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code as *text* inside the question, not as an image. Also, please see these guidelines for creating helpful questions: 
[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: Unless you demote the *expired* DC, I think the DNS may return this expired DC's IP-Address! A *comparatively* better option would be to hard code the available DCs while making the connection, but, again this is not a good practice IMO.

Comment: We have removed the dc from DNS to clear out all records where it could be referenced, this is more of a re-assurance before we demote the server that it is not being used statically by other applications.